# PayPal MECL for iOS 6?

Tags: ios, paypal

Maybe I'm just an idiot but I can't find a download for MECL anywhere.

I need to use MEC, not the SDK, because my target audience includes countries outside the US.

Additionally, according to [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices/) iOS versions above 4.0 are not supported...is this accurate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your question:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/#mobile-sdk-questions